# Android When Keyboard Open Bottom EditText Not Showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, resize

I use RecyclerView with costum row. Costum row has Linear Layout (horizontal) and it has two TextView, one EditText and the row count is 50. So my problem is when keyboard open my bottom EditText now showing, I can just show the EditText with keyboard 'Enter' button. I want to when keyboard open the screen resize or something like that.
I tried that but it's not working. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

My Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/playGameRelative"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FDF2DF"
tools:context=".PlayGameActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/playGameInfoTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#D0C7B7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playGameTxtGameTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/playGameRecycle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playGameInfoTop"
    android:layout_above="@+id/playGameBtnShowResult"/>

<Button.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Costum Row like that:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowGameNumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlue"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rowGameEditText"
    android:text="sokak lambası"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonRegister"
    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext_game"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:enabled="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowGameCorrectAnswer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background_text_game_correct"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried adjustPan as well?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but that's not solution

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root view from your activity like the example below.

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/playGameRelative"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FDF2DF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PlayGameActivity">

    <!-- All your code here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, still same problem

Comment: Do you still have the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` on your activity at your manifest?

Comment: Yes I did. Imagine, I have 30 rows. When I click the 27. EditText, Keyboard pushes 28. -29. - 30. EditText and I can't use scroll to bottom. I must close keyboard and click 28. EditText.